# How to open the default web browser in Windows in C?

Tags: c, windows

In C in Windows, how do I open a website using the default browser? In Mac OS X, I do `system("open http://url");`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to use [`ShellExecute()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea).

The C code to do that is as simple as:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "http://url", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

This was documented by Microsoft Knowledge Base article KB 224816, but unfortunately the article has been retired and there's no archived version of it.

Comment: Link is broken now, do you know where it was moved to?

Comment: An archived version is available at https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/224816

Answer (score 7):

To open a URL in your default browser you could use shell commands and `system()` like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  system("open https://example.com");
}
```

`open` is the default command to open stuff on MacOS, but what happens when you want to open a URL on Windows, Linux, or another operating system?

Well, you will need to change that `open` command.

> On Linux

```
xdg-open <link>
```

> On Windows

```
start <link>
```

> On MacOS

```
open <link>
```

But there is good news, you don't need to handle that, I already created a [module/package/library](https://github.com/abranhe/opener.c) and you can install it using  [**CLIB**](https://github.com/clibs/clib). It is cross-platform, already handle the operating systems stuff, and it is super easy to include it on your project.

**Installation**

```
$ clib install abranhe/opener.c
```

**Usage**

```
#include "opener.h"

int main(void)
{
    opener("https://example.com");
    return 0;
}
```

Since it is written using the shell commands, you are also able to open local directories.

```
// Open current directory
opener(".");
```

Comment: Suggestion: use a different identifier ([`open` has a POSIX meaning](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html)), make the argument `const` and maybe return something to indicate success/failure: `int abranhe_open(const char *url);`

Comment: @pmg thanks for your fast feedback, I'll work on it, `int opening(...)` or `int opn(...)` would be great

Comment: Thanks for this nugget, in my case the answer by lornova didn't work unless I specified the application's path/exe name

Answer (score 4):

In Windows, you can use `start http://url` on the command line to open an URL in the default browser. However, this seems to be specific to the command prompt and is not a real executable, so I don't think you can start it from your C/C++ program.

Comment: `system("cmd /c start http://stackoverflow.com/");` no need to `#include <windows.h>` when using system(), `/c` is for "Run command and then terminate"

Comment: `system("cmd /c start \"\" \"URL\")` so it can handle special chars like &

Comment: Hi netcat, I think you have a typo or two there.  Surely: `system( "cmd /c start \"URL\"" )`

Comment: @SwissFrank, no, @netcat is correct. When passing a speech-mark enclosed argument to `start`, the first argument must be a speech-mark enclosed title for the command window.

Comment: Windows 10 now supports opening a URL without having to pass it through `cmd`. i.e. `system("start \"\" \"http://example.com/page?url=with&parameters#and_anchor\"");` works for me.