# Execute dir command to search for chrome.exe in C:\

Tags: c

I am having some troubles with C. I am using codeblocs and i need to execute the dir command to find where the chrome.exe is. I used;

`system("dir /s /b chrome.exe > desktop\\directory.txt");`

but it says The directory not found because it just searches the folder which my program in it. Can you help me to execute this command in a C program succesfully. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just tell it to start at the root of the drive by prefixing the executable name with a backslash. Also note that `dir` expects the arguments as `[drive:][path][filename] [options]`, so change them to the proper order while you're at it:

```
system("dir \\chrome.exe /s/b > desktop\\directory.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to execute the dir command from the root like:

```
cmd.exe /C "cd\&&dir /s /b chrome.exe > desktop\\directory.txt"
```

The && with the command surrounded on quotes will execute both togheter, so you go to root and then dir withing a cmd.exe

-- answer edited with right command ---

Comment: That will not work! It will try to run a program named "C:\dir.exe" that surely will not exist.

Comment: You don't have to `cd` to the root dir in order for `dir` to work correctly, even at a command prompt.

Comment: @KenWhite But you need to `cd` in order to search from the root, otherwise the cmd will open from default directory and the search will not be completed like OP asked.

Comment: No, you don't. See my answer, which does **NOT** change to the root using `cd`. Test it yourself from a command prompt - change to any folder other than the root of C:\, and then type `dir /s /b \\iexplore.exe` and see for yourself.

Comment: Yep, yours works correctly too, and it's more refined than using the cd

Answer (score 0):

It's not too elegant way to open a browser.

You may [use the default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037088/how-to-open-the-default-web-browser-in-windows-in-c), or if you're sticked to Chrome, you may check [chromiumembedded project](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/). (For Linux, there is an open source embeddable browser, called Surf.)