# How can I open a url in a c++ program

Tags: url, visual-c++, compiler-errors, shellexecute

I tried opening a url in my program but I keep getting errors from "shellapi.h", how can I fix it?

ShellExecuteA(NULL, NULL , "chrome.exe", this->photo.c_str(), NULL, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);

Comment: Post your script and error you are getting to get some help on this.

Comment: Tell us what the errors are.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of c++ library available for this, and here you can find [something](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs).

I have used the following:

- The Silicon C++ Web Framework -siliconframework.org
- IXWebSocket - https://github.com/machinezone/IXWebSocket

Answer (score 1):

Probably better to just use the default browser, like this:

```
// assumes photo.c_str() is valid URL ...
ShellExecuteA(0, NULL, photo.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

Comment: What does one do if this doesn't work/ the default browser isn't found (i.e. `ShellExecuteA()` returns 2)

Comment: In my case, using the system command worked for a default browser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54334181/10530136

Answer (score 0):

For a cross-platform solution, you can set this header:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
static int platform = 1;
#elif _WIN64
static int platform= 1;
#elif __linux__
static int platform = 2;
#elif __APPLE__
static int platform = 3;
#else
static int platform = 0;
#endif
```

and then create a method to open the URL, with the code below:

```
std::string str;
switch(platform) {
    case 1:
       str = "explorer";
       break;
    case 2:
        str = "xdg-open";
        break;
    case 3:
        str = "open";
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Should never happen on the 3 defined platforms" << std::endl;
}
str.append(" " + url);
std::system(str.data());
```

Remember to provide a URL string, in this case a `const std::string& url`.